# suddenly can't connect to router

Tags: router, internet-connection

I was just downloading some stuff in ubuntu and snap, the connection cut and I can't even connect to my router. And the router, it still works fine, my laptop can connect wirelessly to it as usual. But my main computer (which connects to it directly through cable) can't even ping it.

Here is my ipconfig:

```
Windows IP Configuration

        Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : vento
        Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
        Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
        IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8169/8110 Family Gigabit
Ethernet NIC
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-19-DB-4E-6C-56

Ethernet adapter {15B1F740-2F35-4FE4-9FEE-4052AFBAD096}:

        Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Anchorfree HSS Adapter - Packet Sche
duler Miniport
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-15-B1-F7-40
```

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests there's no physical link.  Check:

1. The network cable - swap it for a known good one
2. The switch port - try a different one
3. The network card on the PC - can you try another one?

Comment: Also try to use a static IP in case a new device connecting to the network is assigned the same IP for some reason.